# How can I move an element inside a flex div to the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i'm trying to move these bars to the right next to the logout button.

This is the current style.

```css
.p-menubar-button {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I have tried to **align-content: flex-end** but it doesn't move it.

[This is what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAfqz.png)

Comment: please post the entire code

Answer (score 0):

this might work , try adding :

flex:1;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This works

```css
.p-menubar-button {
  margin-left: auto;
  order: 1;
}
```

And then for the class used on the logout button, I use order: 2.

Answer (score -2):

```
.p-menubar-button {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 18cm;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a suficient explaination of your possible solution.

Comment: `18cm` is an invalid value unless in combination with `print`. Also it is just a wild guess that is not applicable. what do you do on phones with just a width of ~5cm?